# Advise needed - Running Python code on GOOGLE CLOUD PLATFORM serverless

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

I have a python code which reads data from one cloud system via rest api using the requests module and then writes data back to another cloud system via rest api . This code runs anywhere from 1 to 4 hours every week. Is there a place in Google Cloud Platform , I can execute this code on a periodic basis. Sort of like a scheduled batch job . Is there a serverless option to  do this in App Engine . I know about the App engine cron service but seems like it is only for calling a URL  regularly . Any thoughts ? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/) could be the tool you are looking for. As it is mentioned in its documentation:

> Cloud Scheduler is a fully managed enterprise-grade cron job scheduler. It allows you to schedule virtually any job, **including batch**, big data jobs, cloud infrastructure operations, and more. You can automate everything, including retries in case of failure to reduce manual toil and intervention.

Here you have the [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/quickstart) for Cloud Scheduler, and also [another tutorial for Cron jobs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml#cron_support_in_the_console).

Comment: I just wanted to add to notice that Cloud Scheduler is in beta.

Comment: I think Cloud scheduer just schedules the job but where do I write, deploy or run the code. App engine ?

Comment: Yes, in your GAE application, within the end point you choose. As you can see in the second tutorial, when the Cron job is defined, you specify a url. That is the endpoint in your application where you can introduce the code you want to run when the Cron job is triggered.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So if my understanding is correct ; I wrap the python code into a python flask app and then call the same from a url like **.appspot.com and execute the code and get the result . This GAE app I can call using the cron job . Am I understanding it correctly ?

Comment: You will have different endpoints in your application. Let me show you with a little example. Let's say you have this endpoint in your app: `@app.route('/test')`, bound to the function `test()`. Inside the function bound to that endpoint, you will write your code. Now, in your cron.yaml, you will schedule the job, indicating the url for that endpoint (`url: /test`). That way, when the cron job is triggered (according to your desired specifications), the code inside the function `test()` will run.

Comment: Hello there. The python script we want to run in GAE runs for 30 min . Is there a time limit for processing a request in GAE via cron job ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Google Genomics API** `pipelines.run` endpoint to run a long-running job on a **Google Compute Engine** virtual machine and then it will destroy the machine when it's done. If your job will run for less than 24 hours and it can handle a failure, then you can use a **Preemptible VM** to save cost.

**Pipelines: Run**

https://cloud.google.com/genomics/reference/rest/v2alpha1/pipelines/run

**Preemptible Virtual Machines**

https://cloud.google.com/preemptible-vms/

You could use **Cloud Scheduler** to kick off the job

Pipelines may be preferred to trying to use one of the serverless technologies because they don't tend to handle the long running jobs as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AI Platform Training to run any arbitrary Python package — it doesn’t have to be a machine learning job.